# Filter JTable based on three float inputs?

Tags: java, filter, rowfilter

I am trying to filter the rows of a table that respond to the combination of 3 inputs in textField , the input values are floats . The probleme is when i click on the button to get the result the table is empty and does not contain any data . Here is my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
    float pr = Float.parseFloat(PrbInput.getText());
    float tr = Float.parseFloat(TrafficInput.getText());
    float av = Float.parseFloat(AvgInput.getText());

    sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);

    RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> f1 = RowFilter.numberFilter(RowFilter.ComparisonType.AFTER, pr, 7);
    RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> f2 = RowFilter.numberFilter(RowFilter.ComparisonType.AFTER, tr, 9);
    RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> f3 = RowFilter.numberFilter(RowFilter.ComparisonType.AFTER, av, 21);

    List<RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>> filters = Arrays.asList(f1, f2,f3);
    final RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> filter = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
    sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is very difficult to help you in your current scenario as your question is very vague. Please try to debug your program first to narrow the issue down. Then come back, edit your question to include the additional details you found during debugging and we will be happy to help :)

Comment: Hello , @vatbub ! Thank you for answering me . The problem is that no error is generated , i have absolutely no error while running , but when i clicked in the button to get the result , all the data in my table disappear and nothing happened :(

Comment: Therefore, set a breakpoint in the code where you think that the issue might occur, then step through your code step by step and check all variable values to see if something unexpected happens. If you are using IntelliJ, see [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html), for Eclipse, see [this guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)